# Bokeh labels truncated on x Axis

Tags: bokeh

I have created a chart with Bokeh, where the X-Axis is of type 'datetime'.
Unfortunately the labels shown on the X Axis are truncated.
How can I prevent this truncation?

This is my code:

```
TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1000, plot_height=600, title = "Feed")
p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
        hours=["%d %B %Y"],
        days=["%d %B %Y"],
        months=["%d %B %Y"],
        years=["%d %B %Y"],
    )
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3

p.line(_df.datetime, [i for i in range(len(_df.datetime))], color='firebrick', legend='Fast Ask')


output_file("bokeh.html", title="example")
output_notebook()

show(p)  # open a browser
```

And this is the chart:

[image]

Thanks,
Gerald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reference documentation for `DatetimeTickFormatter`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter):

> DatetimeTickFormatter has the following properties (listed together with their default values) that can be used to control the formatting of axis ticks at different scales scales:
>
> ```
> microseconds = ['%fus']
>
> milliseconds = ['%3Nms', '%S.%3Ns']
>
> seconds = ['%Ss']
>
> minsec = [':%M:%S']
>
> minutes = [':%M', '%Mm']
>
> hourmin = ['%H:%M']
>
> hours = ['%Hh', '%H:%M']
>
> days = ['%m/%d', '%a%d']
>
> months = ['%m/%Y', '%b%y']
>
> years = ['%Y']
> ```

You are only setting the last four scales, starting with `hours`. But from your picture it's clear that the x-axis range only extends over the scale of minutes, so Bokeh is using the default format for minutes scales, shown above. If you want a "full" label for smaller scales(e.g. `hourmin` and `minutes` or smaller ones), then you need to configure those as well when you create your `DatetimeTickFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!